# apache orc reader close

Tags: orc

I'm using org.apache.orc.OrcFile.createReader
This lib is fine to read Orc files but I don't find any close method.
Is it normal?

```
val fic=OrcFile.createReader(new Path(element), OrcFile.readerOptions(conf));
val  rows:RecordReader = fic.rows();
        while (rows.nextBatch(batch)) {
          println ("number of rows"+batch.size) 
        }
// fic.close ??
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RecordReader` does have a `close()` method, and I solved my problem (“file is open in another program”) by calling it.

Comment: So you’re proposing `rec.close()` then?

Comment: Yes, it may solve his problem.